# PayPal IPN verified handshake but Invalid IPN

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm having trouble using my "old" PayPal IPN code.
When I use the PayPal IPN Simulator I get the message `IPN was sent and the handshake was verified.` but in my log I can see that the IPN message is `Invalid`

I already checked the following:

- Server supports SHA2 and has SHA2 SSL certificate
- IPN is activated for the merchant account
- IPN URL is correct
- PayPal button language encoding set to UTF-8

**Code I use**

```
        define("DEBUG", true);
        define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);

        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();

        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2)
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }

        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }

        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
            $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        } else {
            $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        }

        $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);

        if ($ch == FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

        if(DEBUG == true) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
        }

        //si depronto se usa proxy eliminar los //
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

        //se coloca el tiempo maximo que se demora este script
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

        $res = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
            {
            if(DEBUG == true) { 
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "No se puede conectar a PayPal para validar el IPN: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            exit;
        } else {
                if(DEBUG == true) {
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." over IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP respnse a la validacion: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                }
                curl_close($ch);
        }

        $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
        $res = trim(end($tokens));

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
            //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
            //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
            //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
            //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
            //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

            $txt = fopen("paypalLog.txt", "a+");

            ob_start();
            var_dump($_POST);
            $result = ob_get_clean();

            fputs($txt, $result);
            @fclose($fp);
            //fin

            // crea el LOG
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "IPN Verification: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "IPN Validation: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
        }
```

**Log file**

```
[2016-10-09 09:49 Europe/Berlin] HTTP response:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1

Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com

Accept: */*

Connection: Close

Content-Length: 938

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded



 over IPN: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Sun+Oct+09+2016+09%3A43%3A26+GMT+0200+%28Mitteleurop%E4ische+Sommerzeit%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=911158411&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Abb2NUi36uV.Fg6Hd45FbjL
[2016-10-09 09:49 Europe/Berlin] HTTP respnse a la validacion: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Sun, 09 Oct 2016 07:49:50 GMT

Server: Apache

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=0UL2ykO4iVuB1THqg4V_A1yKQujjM6s4YtickDFcjh59dGheER5gsdGdmZZCbEMgaMmN3I_R2w7FGJZfAT-b-iu--TRNYPmz3sNcg65cP4NX_3N8vLL5YRk_wP4ng3sV9Z3McJOb8ZG0zTMTQXFAqNee8dS5HvEPSBGxiANK5LjhfcvpbotfTs4OUc-IpsuB3DouU2MaWlABlVdH733KqBHIIPLGrxy9USjIiaf5DS3KhJ-i0RwH3PVy0DOAr0_dWjahWdwr9ulHq11ZhUpD8S6lntr6iZtHNNGZblK_SH-RAA__EZe29-pw1HQAqu-R5-VY0ff9-oEgHfWUB8DzzsAg3dtF2us-ucVhShoSDJcm_ScOgU62vaFkuC1BLEbDJgs0NG9U3NngCZQo59X_7MrfOON8ofxREAKK1yaqdxpI9gWFz1Jrzcbe8KzW; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Wed, 07-Oct-2026 07:49:51 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Tue, 09-Oct-2018 07:49:51 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: Apache=10.42.101.60.1356986390240295; path=/; expires=Tue, 02-Oct-46 07:49:50 GMT

Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

Connection: close

HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc

Paypal-Debug-Id: beb3b1rt5fd1

Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D2666985815%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc; Expires=Sun, 09 Oct 2016 08:19:51 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8



INVALID
[2016-10-09 09:49 Europe/Berlin] IPN Invalido: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Sun+Oct+09+2016+09%3A43%3A26+GMT+0200+%28Mitteleurop%E4ische+Sommerzeit%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=911158411&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Abb2NUi36uV.Fg6Hd45FbjL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the problem. There are a few things that need to be obeserved when using the PayPal Sandbox:

- When you use the **PayPal IPN Simulator**, the **response** you get will always be `Invalid`.
- The PayPal Sandbox **IPN Response can be delayed by minutes** (not only seconds) so it's important to wait a bit to see if there is a response incoming or not.
- For some reasons, PayPal Sandbox doesn't deliver a response, if the PayPal Sandbox Account has the exact **same mail adresse as the real PayPal account**.

By considering the indicated things above, I've fixed my problem.
Hope this will help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given suggests that you are using Sanbox for debugging. So you will have to check that Paypal form action has the sanbox link and your business account is of sanbox as well.

If you want to use the actual paypal account then just change the second line to  `define("USE_SANDBOX", 0);`

Comment: Thx for the reply, but that's not the problem. Every link and the connected PayPal accounts are all sandbox accounts for testing purposes only.